# How to configure virtual hosts to work in htdocs directory of Xampp?

Tags: laravel, apache, xampp, vhosts, laravel-6

I am following a laravel tutorial, where tutor sets up a virtual host to run their app. The app is located in `/opt/lampp/htdocs/first-app`. My port for running apache is **8000**. So if I visit `localhost:8000/first-app/public`, I can view my laravel app.

My httpd-vhosts.conf file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias www.localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8000>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/first-app/public"
  ServerName app.test
  ServerAlias www.app.test

  <Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/first-app">
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My /etc/hosts file looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost app.test
::1             localhost app.test
127.0.1.1       pop-os.localdomain      pop-os
127.0.0.1       app.test
```

I have uncommented httpd.conf like so

```
# Virtual hosts
Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

But I am getting this when I visit app.test

[Browser output when app.test is visited](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hctJ.png)

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit: I have discovered, if I visit www.app.test:8000, it works fine**

Comment: when you edited vhost.conf did you open it as administrator

Comment: Yes I did. It saved properly. Look at my latest edit of the post. Adding port number seems to make it work. But is it possible to do this without specifying port number? I have also changed the DocumentRoot to "/opt/lampp/htdocs/first-app/public" in order to make this work

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that the browser automatically adds port 80. So since I am running apache on port 8000, I need to specify it.

Thus, the settings above actually worked. All I had to do was go to `http://localhost:8000` or `http://127.0.0.1:8000`